# Take multiple .zip files and extract them to external location

Tags: windows, zip, extract, dropbox

This is something that I thought would be extremely simple to do. A math teacher handles her notes through Dropbox and gets .zip files emailed to her containing updates (by updates- they're the full folders so she can delete the old and extract the new ones in their places). She asked if it was possible to extract the zip files, then copy them to the dropbox. Coming from a Linux/Mac point of view I thought it would be easy- unzip command with -d... Little did I know Windows doesn't support unzip. I've tried googling ways to do this, and found that windows doesn't seem to have a default 'unzip' command of any kind? And when trying to copy the files, wildcards don't work either??? She gets 7+ .zip files at a time, all are named "Unit (number).zip" So I was using Unit*.zip. Any help/ideas would be appreciated- I already suggested she tries ubuntu because she constantly states how she likes the way my laptop looks.

Comment: You need to find a tool, such as 7zip, and distribute it with your application and use it for unzipping. As it stands, this question is probably too broad to receive a good answer. Try to narrow it down and ask a specific question.

Comment: Why did you tag this math?

Comment: This question is not about programming, but about using user-level tools. I've just voted to close as off-topic, since [Super User](http://superuser.com/) is a much more appropriate forum for this kind of question. That said, have a look at http://cygwin.com/ if you want to port your Linux command line workflow to a Windows environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinZip can quickly unzip multiple files through its drag and drop interface. You can select multiple WinZip files, right click, and drag them to a folder to unzip them all with one operation.

```
From an open folder window, highlight the WinZip files you want to Extract
Right click in the highlighted area and drag to the destination folder
Release the right mouse button
Choose WinZip Extract to here
```

To unzip multiple Zip files without drag and drop:

```
From an open folder window, highlight the WinZip files you want to Extract
Right click in the highlighted area
Choose WinZip Extract to ...
Enter the destination folder
```

Source http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/77/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the GUI for this:

Here is a trick I have found for extracting multiple zips at once without installing any extra programs:

1. Select the zip files that you want to extract
2. Right-drag them to an empty space (in the same folder is fine)
3. Select Extract and follow the prompts

Yes, it is not quite as nice as using the command prompt, but it does get the job done.

Also, wildcards do work with command prompt. Perhaps you weren't issuing the command correctly. This command works fine for me:

```
copy Unit*.zip D:\folder2\
```